# Building a varying list of optional regular expression segments using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to add optional segments to a routing engine that I wrote. I can handle a single optional segments fine:

```
'/user/(:num?)'
```

Gets translated to:

```
'/user(?:/([0-9]+))?'
```

However, I'm not sure how to handle any number of optional segments:

```
'/user/(:num?)/(:num?)'
```

Should get translated to:

```
'/user(?:/([0-9]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?)?'
```

Obviously, the regular expression is getting more complex with each optional segment that is added. Is there a way I can accomplish this translation in PHP so that any number of optional parameters will be allowed?

### Edit

This is the solution I came up with:

```
$replacements = 0;

$route = str_replace(array('/(:num?)', '/(:any?)'), array('(?:/([0-9]+)', '(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)'), $route, $replacements);
$route .= implode('', array_fill(0, $replacements, ')?'));
```

Comment: And what should happen to `/foo/(:num?)/bar` and `/foo/(:num?)/bar/(:num?)/baz`?

Comment: @Qtax: I didn't intend to account for optional parameters in the middle of URIs, so I'm not worried about that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use split() on / and then loop through the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: Not sure how split helps me here. The regular expressions become nested as optional segments are added.

Comment: Regex doesn't do looping, so if you know you have a series of segments delimited by `/` you should split on `/` and apply regex to each segment. Regex isn't a one-size-fits-all solution. Break it into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a parser that consumes the fixed part of the routing url, then it would create a regexp "context", say a list to store each of the following patterns. After that you transverse the list adding the patterns to something like "(< pattern1 >< pattern2 >)?".

At least that's how I would start to tackle the problem.